# How Can I scroll page up after button click?

Tags: jquery

I have this html code with registration form and I need scroll page up after the click on 
button with class .reg. The problem is that the page scroll only to up border of form.

```
<div class='registration borders'>

<form action="{$web_path}/model/user/userRegistration.php" method="post">

<input class='user' type='text' name='user' autofocus required placeholder="uživatelské jméno">
<input class='email' type='email' name='email' required placeholder="Váš e-mail">

<input class='password' type='password' name='password' required placeholder="uživatelské heslo">

<button class='reg' type='submit' name='registration_sent'>ZAREGISTROVAT</button>

</form>

</div>
```

**Javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var button_reg = $('button.reg');
    button_reg.click(function () {

        // scroll top
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 'slow');
    });

    // end jquery
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#your_respective_div").offset().top}, 1000);
});
})
```

Comment: Problem is that the input has a attribute autofocus and this is the focus on input. When I clear this, so i can use only redirect for example to homepage and the page refresh to the default position.